# Visual studio find all Assert.IsTrue that have no message

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to find using visual studio regular expressions (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx) all calls to Assert.IsTrue that only pass the Boolean argument, for example Assert.IsTrue(parameter) would be one and `Assert.IsTrue(parameter, "message")` wouldn'
t.

For simple things, `Assert.IsTrue\(([a-zA-Z ]+)\)`  does the trick, this works for the example provided above but not for things when there are evaluations done for example Assert.IsTrue(2 > 3). For this I tried using `Assert.IsTrue\((.+[^,])\)` so it matches everything that doesn't have "," but this only filters when the , is at the end, I'm not sure how to filter commas inside.

Finally, what I really want to do (which I'm not sure if it's possible with regular expressions alone) is to find Assert.IsTrue that have only one parameter but this parameter could be a method call, so it could have commas or not, something like `Assert.IsTrue(isTrue(p1,p2))`

Comment: Regex cannot tell `IsTrue` from `CountElements` so you last requirement is impossible. However, you might assume that all boolean method names start with Is, then it is feasible. Please precise requirements and provide generalized examples, then it will be possible to answer the question.

Comment: I was fearing it would be impossible. The method call could have any name and any number of parameter, and it could be called from an object or not something like: `Assert.IsTrue(object?.methodName({p1,}*))`, so, the example I provided is a possibility, another could be `Assert.IsTrue(cat.eatsMouse(mouse1, mouse2))` or without parameters, etc. If this is not possible, is there a way to exclude the "," inside the parentheses? The `Assert.IsTrue\((.+[^,])\)` only excludes when the , is at the end, but not when there is something after the , and before the )

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand what "exlude the comma inside the parentheses" mean. Please state with examples what you want to match and what you want to avoid to match. To just match `Assert.IsTrue()` where inside the parentheses there can be only one method, you can use [`Assert\.IsTrue\([^(),]*(?:\([^()]*\)[^(),]*)*\)`](http://goo.gl/GXBWH3), but it is rather unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want the solution to be programmatically, but if it's ok for you to have a Visual Studio based solution, you could just look for an example of `Assert.IsTrue(parameter);`, right click the method and select "Find all references`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the .+ from your second example and add a * also you should escape the period directly after Assert.

```
Assert\.IsTrue\(([^,])*\)
```

As for your expanded expression, something like this might work.

```
Assert\.IsTrue\(([a-zA-Z\.])*\(.*\)\)
```

This should let you find what you're looking for.